# General Programming: Is it better to do everything on one line instead of in steps?

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie, and I ran into a problem in a lot of the online courses/free information I've been looking at.

When is it better to "do everything on one line" rather than to piece it out step-by-step? In general, I like to do everything step by step, since it makes things easier to read and to debug; however, most solutions I look at do everything in "one big shot". For example, doing the Javascript from Javascript.info, there was a question that required splitting an input string, capitalizing items in an array, and then returning a string of the new array.

My Solution:

```
>let arr = input.split("-"); 
>//Step 1 - split the string
>let modified = arr.map((word, idx) => (idx > 0 ? word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + >word.slice(1) : word ) ); 
>//Step 2- capitalize every first letter except the first index
>return modified.join(""); //step 3- return new joined string
```

Presented the solution:

```
return str
        .split('-') // my-long-word -> ['my', 'long', 'word']
        .map( 
          (word, index) => index == 0 ? word : word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
        ) 
// ['my', 'long', 'word'] -> ['my', 'Long', 'Word']
        .join(''); // ['my', 'Long', 'Word'] -> myLongWord
```

Is it better to do everything in one shot? I understand that technically the presented solution is better (uses less variables, and thus memory). Should I be trying to get in the habit of doing everything in 1 big shot? Is this a good practice to have when I'm (a few years down the road) interviewing for companies? The first solution makes things much easier to understand for me, and I would guess for anyone else who looks at my code later.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Whether to chain methods or not, in general, is often just a matter of style and either can be acceptable. The memory difference for additional variables is negligible since the values/objects being stored in them exist regardless. – For the sake of interviewing, I'd say you'll want to try to eventually become comfortable with chaining, but don't feel you have to go out of your way to use it. – Note: [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), also [fluent interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: Almost never do too much in one step, unless it is `readable`. Assume someone else will have to read your code AND understand it

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best would be:

```
 ["my", "long", "word"].reduce((res, w) => res + w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1))
```

Comment: This is a fair suggestion, but doesn't necessarily answer the question being asked.